# discord reaction bot in python. get_member() in on_raw_reaction_remove() always gets 'none'

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have this python code where my Bot should remove Roles from the user if the user removes his reaction from a Message with the given message ID.
I dont know why, but I always get 'none' and the bot cant remove the role because he cant find the member...
The intents in the discord developer portal are active. I dont know what I've been doing wrong.
Can somebody help me here please?

```
import discord
from discord import message, ActivityType
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Cog
from discord.utils import get
from discord import utils

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True, presences=True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$', intents=intents)

class reaction_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client 

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):          
        message_id = payload.message_id

        if message_id == 829409323297407027:
            guild = self.client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
            user = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=str(payload.emoji.name))
            print(role)
            print(user)
            if user != None:
                user = payload.member 
                print(user) 
                if user != None:
                    await user.remove_roles(role)
```

EDIT:

Thank you for your help.
that with the roles is not a problem. They are easily recognized. It is recognized which reaction is added and which is removed. Only my user stays at none.

I added a few prints to demonstrate what the code does.

```
message_id = payload.message_id
        if message_id == 829409323297407027:
            guild = self.client.get_guild(payload.guild_id

            print("remove action starts")
            print("Reaction removed on server:")
            print(guild)
            user = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=str(payload.emoji.name))
            print("Which Role removed:")
            print(role)
            print("user who removed:")
            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                user = payload.member 
                print(user) 
                if role is not None:
                    await user.remove_roles(role)
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
remove action starts
Reaction removed on server:
Danis Server
Which Role removed:
Uni
user who removed:
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make sense to me at some parts. You have to actually define which role you want to remove on reaction. You can do that in different ways.

**Take a look at the following code:**

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        guild = self.client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # Get the member
        if payload.message_id == YourMessageID:
            if str(payload.emoji) == "YourEmoji":
                role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='RoleName') # ID also possible
            else:
                role = get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)

            if role is not None:
                await member.remove_roles(role) # Remove role
```

You can also add more `elif`-statements if you want to remove more roles than just one.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited my problem. Can you maybe take a look at it?